# Outputting debug information in console

Tags: java, swing, debugging, console

I am doing a `Java` application, which will use `swing` user interface. It will ask user to specify some settings, by filling in forms, and then process them and generate some files in the `./output/` directory.

During development process, I'd like to output some technical information in console, using `System.out.println()` method.

Do I need to remove all these console outputs when I'll finish development?

If yes, what is the best way to display debug information during development process to easily remove it before production?

Maybe I should use only `JUnit` tests for debugging purposes? I've just started with it, so I have vague idea of ​​its capabilities.

Comment: [Log4J 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) is meant to help you in that, many a features it is packed with, which you can see at that link :-)

Comment: In some cases, Java logging may be better

Comment: @Siorus Can you briefly explain? And what you mean by `Java logging`?

Comment: If you need information like: DB connection start/stop/query, catched excelptions etc. you can use this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're not going to use a specialised debugging framework it could be as easy as:

```
if (Debugger.isEnabled())
    Debugger.log("message here");
```

The Debugger class just encapsulates the println calls (like this):

```
public class Debugger{
    public static boolean isEnabled(){
        return true;
    }

    public static void log(Object o){
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}
```

That way when you want to go to production, or you can modify the behavior of your debugging (or disable it) by changing one line in a class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll, probably, better try some debugging framework, as you mentioned. :)

Comment: I tried this but it said `non-static method Debugger cannot be accessed from static content`

Answer (score 9):

A small improvement to the Debugger class to make the client a little cleaner:

```
public static void log(Object o){
    if(Debugger.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }           
}
```

Then the client side would need just one line:

```
Debugger.log("....")
```

Comment: This is not a better solution in my opinion. Often debug message strings need formatting and this takes CPU time even when debugging is disabled. Checking for debugging outside the call to `log()` saves that (the branch occurs anyway). Alternatively, you can have a `log()` method that wraps string formatting.